# Couchbase says: No valid node found to bootstrap from

Tags: couchbase

What means this error message ?

```
com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: No valid node found to bootstrap from. Please check your network configuration.
```

From the source code:

```
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/message/cluster/SeedNodesRequest.java
```

it looks like my node host is found, but is not valid:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, it means that the Couchbase SDK cannot connect to the cluster you have in your connect string in your connection object. It is trying to connect and get the cluster map to know the cluster topology, what services are available and where in the cluster they are.

In the future, please add your code you are using to your question so as to have people answer your question, but also benefit the community here.

Comment: I had to explicitly specify a design document with the designDocument = DESIGN_DOCUMENT attribute of the @View annotation on the repository method. Indeed my domain class name is slightly different than the design document. Thus the default value (the domain class name) was wrong. Also my IP for the host was invalid.